# Distribute table columns equally over the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a content placed in a table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="anliegenGrammatik"></table>
```

and this is my jQuery where I have AJAX request and using the response I populate (append) the table above.

```
success: function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index) {
        $.each(response[index].synonyms, function(index2) {
            $('#anliegenGrammatik').append('<tr> <td>' + response[index].synonyms[index2] + '</td> </tr>');
        });
    });
},
```

But it has a lot of data and like this it produces several hundred rows. How can I make in jQuery that it distributes columns and rows equally over the page. For example, instead of having one `<tr>` with 100 `<td>`s, I would like to have 4 `<tr>` and 25 `<td>`s in each row.

Is this even possible?

Comment: add a counter and if it reach the number of columns add a new tr

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that you get in your AJAX.

Comment: @Alex It is array of simple strings. I just need to output them...

Comment: @mbadeveloper had an interesting idea.

Comment: I agree. I'm trying to make it that way.

Comment: @harunB10 I dont have clear if the inner each have the column information

Answer (score 0):

```js
success: function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index) {
        var item = 1;
        var totalItems = response[index].synonyms.length;       
        var numRows = 4; // number of rows
         var cellsRow =  Math.floor(totalItems/numRows); // number of cells per row
        var cells = '';
        
        $.each(response[index].synonyms, function(index2) {
        
            cells += '<td>' + response[index].synonyms[index2] + '</td>'; 
            
            if((item % cellsRow == 0) || item == totalItems)
            {
              $('#anliegenGrammatik').append('<tr>'+cells+'</tr>');
              cells = '';
            }                       
            item ++;
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: In my case it never goes into this if statement. And because of that the table is never filled. :/

Comment: There is only one... `if((item % cellsRow == 0) || item == totalItems)`

Comment: @harunB10 can you debug it and find what is the value of totalItems ?

Comment: For testing I do not use so much data. Right now `totalItems = 25`. There was a typo in "length" though.